# How to store data in database with Form API?

Tags: 7, forms, database

I'm new to developing Drupal 7 modules, and I can't figure out why my custom module's form data is not stored in my database's table called '`media_skins`'.

I followed the info explained in [Creating modules - a tutorial: Drupal 7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360) but I can't get it working. What's wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
function media_skins_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/content/media_skins'] = array(
    'title' => 'Media Skins',
    'description' => 'Configuration for Skins module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('media_skins_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function media_skins_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['media_skins_test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Test field'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#description' => t('Test info for the field.'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function media_skins_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    // For now, I will no validate anything
}

function media_skins_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = db_insert('media_skins')->fields(
    array(
      'start_date' => $form_state['values']['media_skins_test'],      
    )
  )
  ->execute();
  drupal_set_message('Data stored in database successfully'); 
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDITING THE SCENARIO**

After reading your comments, I tried the following, but I get "Unexpected error, try it again":

```
function media_skins_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['media_skins_test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Test field'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#description' => t('Test info for the field.'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Enviar'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Try getting rid of `system_settings_form($form)` in the form function, and simply use `return $form;`. Also check that you are really getting values in `$form_state['values']['media_skins_test']` by using `dpm()` (install Devel module) or by doing a `drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['media_skins_test']);` in the submit handler

Comment: A couple clarifications about configuration forms. Using `system_settings_form($form)` creates an automatic submit handler that basically assigns the submitted values to Drupal variables named by the keys of the $form array. In your case, using  `system_settings_form($form)` assigns the submitted value to the Drupal variable `media_skins_test`. Drupal variables ARE STORED in the database table called `variable`. There is no need for you to create a custom handler to store the submitted value in a different table if you are using `system_settings_form($form)`

Comment: also create a file "media_skins.install" in your custom module

Comment: try this :'start_date' => $form_state['input']['media_skins_test'],

Comment: Please check out my edited version, getting rid of `system_settings_form($form) ` What's worng on it? I can't figure out what's happenning

Answer (score 0):

To use your own form submit handler, you should not use **system_settings_form** in your form, instead just return your form.

If you are just going to save your value in your submit handler, go with **system_settings_form**. 
To get the values, use `variable_get('your form field name')`. In your case, you can use `variable_get('media_skins_test');`

Comment: Yeah, but, where I shall to use `variable_get`? In the submit form? Instead `'start_date' => $form_state['input']['media_skins_test']` maybe?

Comment: Are you going to do any custom functionality in your submit handler?

Comment: I only want to store on a db table the data retrieved from the inputs. Nothing else. I don't know if it can be called 'functionality'.

Comment: okay. I seen your edited question. Please post your recent log error message at (admin/reports/dblog) when you tried to submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to variable_get like below.Now you can get the values why because it will store in the variable table.

```
function media_skins_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/content/media_skins'] = array(
    'title' => 'Media Skins',
    'description' => 'Configuration for Skins module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('media_skins_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function media_skins_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['media_skins_test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Test field'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#description' => t('Test info for the field.'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('media_skins_test', 10),
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function media_skins_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    variable_set('media_skins_test', $edit['demo_number']);

}
```

in devel/php you can see the results of the textfield

$test = variable_get('media_skins_test');
dpm($test);